# Vertical alignment of form-controls with wrapping labels in a row with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have input elements in a row with labels above of the input fields. When the screen width is narrowed down the longer labels consisting of several words warp to the next line and shift the input element down, making the overall row higher:

[image: Inputs with broken alignment]

The wrapping of the text would be fine, but I'd want the other inputs, which have no wrapping labels, to align with the one that is shifted down.

How can I achieve this? I would like to find another solution than using an ellipsis...

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <div ><label>Short Label</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <div ><label>This label is too long</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <div ><label>Another label</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new `align-items-end` class ([Alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#alignment))

```
<div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <div ><label>Short Label</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <div ><label>This label is too long</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <div ><label>Another label</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace class `col-md-4` to `col`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col form-group">
        <div ><label>Short Label</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
        <div ><label>This label is too long</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
        <div ><label>Another label</label></div>
        <div ><input class="form-control" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem of wrapping the text for smaller screen width

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is

```
<div class="row align-items-baseline">
```

Immagine to have one text field on the left and a textarea on the right,
using "align-items-end" you will have the bottom border of text field at the same level of the bottom border of the text area.
With "align-items-baseline" top borders of the two elements are at the same level, i found this way better.